# While using DRF APIView with drf_yasg appears additional POST query, that i have not defined

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, drf-yasg

I have got this urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('users/', UserApiView.as_view()),
    path('users/<str:pk>/', UserApiView.as_view()),
]
```

and APIView class:

```
class UserApiView(APIView):

    @swagger_auto_schema(
        request_body=CreateUserSerializer,
        responses={'200': openapi.Response('response description', DetailUserSerializer(many=True))}
    )
    def post(self, request):
        user_data = CreateUserSerializer(request.data)
        user_data.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        new_user = user_data.save()
        return Response(DetailUserSerializer(new_user).data)

    @swagger_auto_schema(
        responses={'200': openapi.Response('response description', DetailUserSerializer)}
    )
    def get(self, request):
        queryset = UserRepo().get_all()
        serializer = DetailUserSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response({'data': serializer.data})

    @swagger_auto_schema(
        responses={'200': openapi.Response('response description',               DetailUserSerializer(many=True))}
    )
    def get(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = UserRepo().get_all()
        user = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)

        serializer = DetailUserSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

but in swagger i see extra /users/{id}/ POST query (it's the last one)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rWx5.png)

I tried to find something in drf_yasg docs, but it was not successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem dividing UserApiView to several different classes. One of them handles users/, another one /users/pk
so, no more redundant docs